# Accessing a JSP via a Servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, model-view-controller

I am learning Java EE and I'm pretty new to MVC development, thank you in advance for your patience.

I'm trying to write a simple JSP accessible via a servlet, but I am getting a 404 error when I try to reach the following URLs :

> http://localhost:8080/pro/inscription
>
> http://localhost:8080/inscription

I don't see where I went wrong, or what I forgot to write. 
I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Here is the Project Tree Structure (Eclipse):

[image]

Here are the files I have developed.

> inscription.jsp

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Inscription</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/inc/styles/css/form.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="inscription">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Inscription</legend>
            <p>Vous pouvez vous inscrire via ce formulaire.</p>

            <label for="email">Adresse email <span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="20"
                maxlength="60" /> <br /> <label for="motdepasse">Mot de
                passe <span class="requis">*</span>
            </label> <input type="password" id="motdepasse" name="motdepasse" value=""
                size="20" maxlength="20" /> <br /> <label for="confirmation">Confirmation
                du mot de passe <span class="requis">*</span>
            </label> <input type="password" id="confirmation" name="confirmation"
                value="" size="20" maxlength="20" /> <br /> <label for="nom">Nom
                d'utilisateur</label> <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" value=""
                size="20" maxlength="20" /> <br /> <input type="submit"
                value="Inscription" class="sansLabel" /> <br />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http:/'2Fwww.w3.mrg/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>pro</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Inscription</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.Inscription</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>Auteur</param-name>
        <param-value>Imad</param-value>
    </init-param>   

  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Inscription</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/inscription</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

> Inscription.java -The servlet

```
package servlets;


import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Inscription extends HttpServlet
{
    /**
     * UID
     */
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 7413041593835021978L;
    /**
     * Path de la vue
     */
    public static final String  VUE                 = "/WEB-INF/incription.jsp";

    @Override
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse resp ) throws ServletException , IOException
    {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( req , resp );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct root context "pro"?

Comment: Yes indeed. As you can see from the project tree and the URLs.

Comment: The context root and the project name are not necessarily the same thing...

Comment: Yes I made sure the context root in the Project's web Properties is 'pro'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an spelling mistake for your `inscription.jsp`

```
public static final String  VUE = "/WEB-INF/incription.jsp";
```

and in you form action you should try like this:

```
action='/pro/inscription' OR action='/inscription'
```

Comment: Indeed, it was a spelling mistake. it is in**s**cription and not incription. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The url-pattern inside of web.xml  defines the path used to access the application

The application URL you posted does concatenate the displayname and the pattern. I think you should get to your application if you pro like
...localhost:8080/inscription

There are many tutorials available to get familiar with the bases as should I use forward or include. I checked this one for this answer

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm

Comment: It doesn't work either way. But thanks for sharing :).